# Computer Modern Bold SF has rounded corners

Tags: fonts, bold, sans-serif, fontfamily

When experimenting with the Beamer class I noticed that when using the default SF font (which is Computer Modern AFAIK) in boldface the corners are rounded. It looks like completely different font. (And I think it is. Look at the shape of the 'o' (oh) which became squared instead of rounded.) I have never seen this before on fonts: bold is usually a bold version of the original font. Is this normal/intentional? Why?

I am creating a template for a presentation in company style so I am not allowed to change the font.

Compare Helvetica in normal and boldface, and compare Computer Modern Sans in normal and boldface.

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{helvet}
\begin{document}
Helvetica\par
\textbf{Helvetica}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
%\usepackage{helvet}
\begin{document}
Computer Modern\par
\textbf {Computer Modern}
\end{document}
```

[image]

On a side note, for this post I had to create two documents. For the life of it, I have not been able to change the font back to Computer Modern Sans. Although I set the document default to Sans, this command would show Computer Modern with serif. Only when I comment out \usepackage{helvet} I can get the Computer Modern font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{helvet}
\begin{document}
Helvetica\par
\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont
Expected Computer Modern Sans here
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `a` of Helvetica is quite different as well though!

Comment: you need cmss instead of cmr for the sans font.

Comment: @Albert: yes, you are right. I don't deny that but it is by far not that obvious as with Computer Modern.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: Makes sense! cmSS instead or cmR. Really impossible to find in Google. Always ending up at  the same guides when searching for "setting font to Computer Modern"

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Would you like to add an answer?

Comment: Note that quotation sans is more rounded in regular weight, at least in Latin Modern. Depending on your usage, this might or might not be of interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Font design is the choice of the font designer.

But regarding the font change: You need to use cmss instead of cmr if you want the computer modern sans font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{helvet}
\begin{document}
Helvetica\par
\fontfamily{cmss}\selectfont
Expected Computer Modern Sans here
\end{document}
```

[image]